# jQuery Navbar transition on scroll. How to adjust specific point of transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a site I'm building I'm trying to make the navbar change color when I scroll. However, I don't want it to change colors as soon as I start scrolling. I want it at a specified point (once I scroll past my jumbotron).

So far, I've only been able to make it work by scrolling from the top. I'm not quite skilled enough to figure out how to do it past a specific point on my page. I would greatly appreciate some guidance on this.

**jQuery script**

```
 $(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".fixed-top");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do it.
one way could be done with pure javascript.
change `changeColorValue` that represents the scroll bar value according to your needs.

Here is my suggestion:
[LIVE DEMO](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=1330ad96-6e2c-4991-a29e-bb41d5282ddf)

JavaScript:

```
var changeColorValue = 50;
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnim);
function scrollAnim () {
  var val = getScrollVal();

  if(val > changeColorValue)
  {
    document.getElementById('mynav').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('mynav').style.backgroundColor = '#333';
  }
}
function getScrollVal()
{
  var val = $(document).scrollTop();
  return val;
}
```